# Displaying an UIViewController that is not present in UITabBarController's controller list

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

Let me give an example what about what I want to do:
I have a tab that has 4 TabBarItems, so it contains 4 controllers. And there is a controller that must not get shown up in tab bar's icons, but it will get shown when a button inside one of these 4 controllers are touched. So when it get's shown, the tabbar must not have any selected tabs, every item must be deselected. It must be like a ghost controller that is not shown in tab icons but it's actually a controller that's in tab bar controller.

What's the best way to achieve this? Fyi, I don't want a modal dialog, the tabbar must always be visible underneath.

Comment: You're trying to break the behavior of a UITabBarController. You could place a UINavigationController in one of the tabs, then push a viewcontroller, but the tab would still be selected. Alternatively, you could add a view to the window, but you'd then get basically modal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which might help is knowing when a transition between tabs is happening.  If you display your ghost view as soon as the transition happens, you might have enough control to do what you want.

Here's how I do that: first, sub-class UITabBarController to TabViewController (for example).  In your TabViewController, include this method:

```
// Pass this message on to views so they know when transitions are occuring
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate> *obj;

    for ( obj in self.viewControllers ) {
        if ( [obj respondsToSelector:_cmd] ) {
            [obj tabBarController:tabBarController didSelectViewController:viewController];
        }
    }
}
```

Set each of your tabbed view classes to adopt the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol.  Then, include a method like this in each class to "intercept" the transition events:

```
// This is called when a transition between tabs happens
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if ( [viewController isEqual:self] ) {
        // Transitioning to me

        // Do stuff
   }    

    else  {
        // Transitioning to someone else

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

(note: there might be cleaner ways of implementing this, but it's been working fine for me...)